# Can't find Spring Framework "Form" taglib documentation

Tags: java, spring, taglib

I've been googling various different things including

`spring taglib form`

`spring form:checkboxes`

and other variations of these.  For the life of me I cannot find clear documentation on how to use this stuff.  Is Spring doing a poor job at SEO or am I not using the right terminology?

I'm trying to find documentation on `form:checkboxes` and `form:options`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms I used on Google:

```
spring 3 mvc reference tag library
```

And one of the top results was: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib

Comment: I'm frustrated that Spring's search feature in their documentation didn't pull this up when I typed in `taglib`.  That seems like a no brainer.  This is very helpful, but it doesn't show attributes that go along with those tag elements.  I'm trying to figure out what attribute I need to pass to get checkboxes to show up vertically not horizontally.

Comment: My suggestion is to re-formulate your question about Spring `form:checkboxes` since the description you give now is not about finding the documentation.

Comment: To supplement, here's Spring's complete reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html